# CSS Custom Radio Button I cannot see the image I want to be displayed

Tags: css, button, radio-button

I am trying to create a custom radio button. But it's not working. I can't see the image I want to display.

```
 label {
   font-weight: lighter;
   cursor:pointer;
 }

 input[type="radio"] {
    display:none;
 }

 input[type="radio"] + label {
    background: url('../img/check-a.png') left 1px no-repeat;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
 }

 input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background-image: url('../img/check-a.png');
 }

 <form onSubmit="submitValue()" id="comp" name="comp" action="https://registration.disneyinternational.com/login.htm" method="get">
    <div class = "row form-row padding-top-20">
       <div class = "col-md-3 text-center wrapper-q1">
          <p>
             <input class="question1" id = "schurk1" type="radio" name="q1" value="Parade">
             <br />
             <label class = "pointer label3" for = "schurk1">
                De Boze Stiefmoeder
             </label>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class = "col-md-3 text-center wrapper-q1">
           <p>
              <input class="question1" id = "schurk2" type="radio" name="q1" value="Parade">
              <br />
              <label class = "pointer label3" for = "schurk2">
                  Cruella
              </label>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class = "col-md-3 text-center wrapper-q1">
            <p>
              <input class="question1" id = "schurk3" type="radio" name="q1" value="Parade">
              <br />
              <label class = "pointer label3" for = "schurk3">
                 Maleficent
              </label>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class = "col-md-3 text-center wrapper-q1">
            <p>
              <input class="question1" id = "schurk4" type="radio" name="q1" value="Parade">
              <br />
              <label class = "pointer label3" for = "schurk4">
                  Jafar
              </label>
            </p>
         </div>
     </div>
 </form>
```

Hope you can help me with this. I am using bootstrap. I worry that potentially the bootstrap code is interfering with my own code.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove all your `<br />`s.

In your CSS, the rule you are using to target your labels is the `+`, or next sibling. The next sibling to your inputs is actually a `<br />` in your current code.

Comment: You can also replace the + with ~ in input[type="radio"] ~ label and input[type="radio"]:checked  ~ label

Comment: Sure, but I don't think the <br>s should be there anyway. It's only for display and is essentially meaningless; that kind of visual styling should be moved to the CSS.

Comment: I totally agree. Just wanted to note that ~ is a possibility.

Comment: Thankyou sir! It was indeed the <br /> that was causing trouble!

Answer (score 2):

The `+` in selector looks for immediate `label` tag. Since there is a `<br>` in between, the label is not selected.

Use `~` instead of `+` which can select any `label` preceded by `input`.

Check the fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/hL0fj82m/